# Expectation value of Polyakov loop

Tags: gauge-theory, yang-mills, wilson-loop

Assuming a pure Yang-Mills theory, how exactly does one get that, for appropriate $\beta$ for confinement, the expectation value of the Polyakov loop $<\Phi>$ equals zero? I do not seem to get the integration right.